# Generate advanced composite type from string literal array

Tags: typescript

Based on a nested object and an array of string literals, I would like to generate a composite type, which contains the keys listed in the string literal array concatenated with their subkeys.

Here is an example:

```js
const data = {
  foo: {
    a: 1,
    b: 'b',
  },
  bar: { c: () => {} },
  baz: { d: 'test', e: 42 },
};
const literals = ['foo', 'baz'] as const satisfies readonly (keyof typeof data)[];

/** MagicFunction is what I'm trying to find */
type magicOutput = MagicFunction<typeof data, typeof literals>;

/** This is what I want the output of MagicFunction to look like */
type expectedOutput = 'foo.a' | 'foo.b' | 'bar' | 'baz.d' | 'baz.e';
```

The closest I've been to a working type definition works only with a single string literal, not with an array of string literals.

```
export type SemiMagicFunction<
  Object extends Record<string, any>,
  Key extends keyof Object extends string ? keyof Object : never
> = keyof Object[Key] extends string ? `${Key}.${keyof Object[Key]}` : never;

// Resulting type is "foo.b" | "foo.a"
type semiMagicOutput = SemiMagicFunction<typeof data, typeof literals[0]>;

// To generate my target output I could hardcode all entries of the literal
type Subtract<A, B> = A extends B ? never : A;
type magicOutput =
  | Subtract<keyof typeof data, typeof literals[number]>
  | SemiMagicFunction<typeof data, typeof literals[0]>
  | SemiMagicFunction<typeof data, typeof literals[1]>;
```

However, I want to not have to update the type definition when the literals array changes. I've already tried using `Keys[number]`, but `Object[Keys[number]]` always returns `never`:

```js
export type NonWorkingMagicFunction<
  Object extends Record<string, any>,
  Keys extends keyof Object extends string ? readonly (keyof Object)[] : never
> = keyof Object[Keys[number]] extends string ? `${Keys[number]}.${keyof Object[Keys[number]]}` : never;

// In this case (if this were to work) the output would have to be combined with Subtract<keyof typeof data, typeof literals[number]> once again
```

Is there a way in TypeScript to accomplish this? I wasn't able to find anything, as mapping types don't work for this, and the indexing does not work either for some reason.

There is also a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgBACgNghgngcwE4HsCuA7AJmAZipMARzQFMBnAFwEsUMwALSygB3IC5hgqYBjAaxQA3UklxQUAdwB0vFAFtgLFFXLAA7AFZNADgCcO9QAYwIYAFgAUFbkYqYLDEowwAXjABvK2DwoU7T28fMBgAgEYAGiCfACMAgHIY+KjLHwBfFNiYJACPMF4AgAoASjcAPk80sAygmJgAL1yHBMoKSmSwUgCAFgAmapS0gG4bOnsoalakGChyNzAAbXj8FA7EhviAXRC523tyJ2pyXGoKMCRSGCw6KDgwQv5SOBRcMEo4FlIXhycYYoXNiNrJZQOAACoMI5gKGSBhOMAASTAkhgGEobwYpDA6FYaHR3wAsjAENReAAxTC8Gh0N4oMASFD8enUR6mCyWd6fToAD0+VNIWAA8niWHj5ss-NIYPEwAAfMASlDSJJyhV1JAy+XrerSLCatUNaSkeJAqxmkEgS1W602212+0Ou3ecGY-ISchtRHxET5BRY8h03DZCJgGJi2GkhjnUgkagXOYgZ0+OFILByLDUDAITp8KOkNFIO7fCZTGZzTMYrGcrE+ROpR0NxtN23sqzVsAAZTQMUo0ypAB4AIIhgBCFXcg55rWwcxHYAA-GAMKQRIQAoPTZZSLyCOj2x3SPJqESSeTKdSMP2goKYgArUhUqf5rBzABKD4IWH7VCQmYQIdROAykyMAAGknifGcwEeZ5Xhve9H23acXzAH8-wXaCnm+eCH3RAJl1XKxx0w2CwBwqkFnAuBtiQ585jQrMMIAAwAEg8Ki0mkNiYOwu9cMop5NjSJiwHwldRE3LgwHfcg0CgGhGPbKEACIVmVZTVVUyUYGUtsPn9Q9j2JUlhVxdF3API8T1JCkMCpWhL2rb5HGcEMnNeEtRDLBYjE2MpJOAMAwTpBB8y81owHkO5nCQUL8RFMUkTkOScBTNMUCwLEZigToC1OOZvkoV1POmKA9K5NL0wFUzRXMoJ5S7Hs+0ofseNedyflct59OLSYvNmBYMDQeQYlEPz6s7QzrLPOyL37DqXJgNyeo8vrSvIHzxtSVVLKM09bPsuh5pWzqlu6z5etLAawj8zdzVBZtHqem0k2CILITma4zgwFB0UkAgmVRHAoRmFE4DmAjRDe4I61MZ74ae1tUm3ZQkD3fSwAAOToAB1AG-2mg65uvPjEO5ZC3w-VNv17P8AIwICQKouZaKgtqyNJ9FWZQhjs0XC4rhuO4HiwuDOf+bYxMIyxiPZ8jKAE8HBuG0akE2Gjybo1DacYxdWPYp4NqGkaxs47jRY5hCFeZ5WTbVoSRKliT7sChF6CKqFeBgD17modqPuRUQqzpf6kH4UoiqxHFauRdAoFSmAfUoOlRt9EbMwFZFJijRrez4Fr2YW35lou1arqNlWxoqOheCyhAYEzcqsR+jA8bDv8arFdxsdb-Gs0J88HOO0vTpLr4y-68gyiAA) with the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This distributive conditional approach seems to work, but could be made more elegant perhaps.

```js
// utility
type MemberOf<Array extends readonly unknown[]> = Array[number];

const DATA = {
  foo: {
    a: 1,
    b: "b",
  },
  bar: { c: () => {} },
  baz: { d: "test", e: 42 },
} as const;

const EXAMPLE_KEYS = ["foo", "baz"] as const satisfies readonly (keyof typeof DATA)[];

type ChildPath<Data, ParentKey extends keyof Data> = ParentKey extends string
  ? keyof Data[ParentKey] extends string
    ? `${ParentKey}.${keyof Data[ParentKey]}`
    : never
  : never;

// hovering over this type gives...
// type ExamplePaths = "foo.b" | "foo.a" | "baz.d" | "baz.e"
type ExamplePaths = ChildPath<typeof DATA, MemberOf<typeof EXAMPLE_KEYS>>;
```

Comment: That's surprisingly similar, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide the full code to get to my exact goal based on the [answer by cefn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75590235/2852578):

```js
/** Subtract a union type from another union type */
type Subtract<A, B> = A extends B ? never : A;

/** Make a union type of the provided keys with their subkeys */
type ChildPaths<Object extends Record<string, any>, KeysOfNested extends keyof Object> = KeysOfNested extends string
  ? keyof Object[KeysOfNested] extends string
    ? `${KeysOfNested}.${keyof Object[KeysOfNested]}`
    : never
  : never;

/** Make a union type with all keys while the KeysOfNested are combined with their subkeys */
type PathsWithSomeNestedKeys<
  Object extends Record<string, any>,
  KeysOfNested extends readonly (keyof Object)[]
> = Subtract<keyof Object, KeysOfNested[number]> | ChildPaths<Object, KeysOfNested[number]>;

const data = {
  foo: {
    a: 1,
    b: 'b',
  },
  bar: { c: () => {} },
  baz: { d: 'test', e: 42 },
};
const literals = ['foo', 'baz'] as const satisfies readonly (keyof typeof data)[];

// This results in exaclty the output I described in my question
type NestedKeys = PathsWithSomeNestedKeys<typeof data, typeof literals>
```